# How do I make ngFor be horizontal with bootstrap?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngfor

I currently have a row and a column. The interests I want to have horizontally, so for this example, it would just show "Music, Technology, Education" in a row. My struggle is to be able to do that. Thank you to everyone who replies, thank you!

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="card text-center">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col sm-6">
     <div class="card text-center">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          Interests
        </h5>
        <div *ngFor="let item of interests">
          <div class="row">
            <span> {{ item }}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: if u use row as class it make display block and fill width